# Jquery is not functioning correctly on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is weird. I have videos on my website. The current time is equal to 13 whenever you hover around it plays on mute. Here's my thing when I test this out on chrome and firefox everything seems to be working fine and for internet explorer it works but in a different way and I mean different the current time for the video is changed to 0 which is very odd to me. Can someone help me please? Tell me what I am doing wrong. By the way I have Internet explorer 8 on my computer Here is my code

```
<script>


//play video on hover



    $(document).on('mouseover', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=true;
    }); 



    //pause video on mouse leave
    $(document).on('mouseleave', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).pause(); 
        this.currentTime = 13;

    });

    $(document).on('click', 'video', function() { 
        $(this).get(0).play();
        this.muted=false;
        this.currentTime = 0;

    });
```

Comment: JQuery only supports IE9+.

Comment: wow seriously. But I'm trying to make my website work across all browsers. I don't want when I submit my website to the world wide web that people start having problems. I can't fix that?

Comment: _I don't want when I submit my website to the world wide web that people start having problems_ You can't make every user happy unfortunately. At this point in time, there are few users who still use IE8. At some point, all developers need to come together and stop supporting IE entirely. Though, if you want to continue supporting IE8, you can use the [old jQuery versions](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x) -- though you'll have to use their old functions as well. I don't think `on()` is used in old versions. I think it's either `live()` or `bind()`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Also its not about making people happy but more so not making things look off but thank you anyways.